# Як у Гоґвортсі називається "High Table" українською?

Tags: переклад, from-english

В старовинних університах Великої Британії, таких як [Оксбридж](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6), проводяться вечері під назвою "High Table Dinner" (див. ["High Table"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Table) у Вікіпедії), які виглядають подібно до вечері у фільмах про Гаррі Поттера.

Може хтось читав Гаррі Поттера українською і знає, як там переклали словосполучення "High Table"? Або які є інші ідеї для перекладу?

Comment: Будь ласка, поясніть своїми словами, що означає цей термін. Я не дивився Гаррі Поттера.

Comment: Звідки ви взяли, що це вечеря? Ви взагалі читали те вікі на, яке посилаєтесь? У вікі, яке ви скинули написано, що High Table - це довгий стіл, за яким люди харчуються, зазвичай в бенкетних залах. Конкретно, на вікі Гаррі Поттера написано, що це був довгий стіл викладачів в бенкетній залі.
https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/High_Table

А бенкети із Гаррі Поттера в українському перекладі, це різні типи feast, пак Welcoming Feast, Start-of-Term Feast, Christmas Feast  і т.д.

-1

Comment: @improbable, я сплутав сам стіл (high table) із сучасним поняттям урочистого бенкету (high table dinner). Підправив своє запитання. — Питання в тому, чи це перекласти просто як «урочистий бенкет», втративши трохи британського контексту з їхнім довгим столом, чи все-таки щось типу «вечеря за високим столом».

Comment: За що друга оцінка вниз? Що це за агресивна спільнота тут у вас? :(

Comment: @improbable тут не заохочується таке спілкування із новими користувачами як "звідки ви взяли". Будь ласка, утримуйтеся в майбутньому від такого тону. Якщо користувач чогось недозрозумів - поясніть йому спокійно.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha я не підтримую аґресивної реакції на ваше запитання, але можу пояснити, чому так стається. Ось [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/), за якими оцінюються хороші питання й відповіді. Спільнота вибаглива й вимагає дотримання цих критеріїв. Це добре, адже підвищує якість інформації на сайті, але аґресивний підхід іноді відлякує. Перепрошую за такий підхід і дуже заохочую почитати критерії (адже за їх дотримання той підхід зникне). Вітаю на нашому сайті й сподіваюсь на плідну співпрацю!

Comment: @P.Vowk, я знаю, як працюють ці спільноти і чим хороше питання відрізняється від поганого. Але я не розумію чим це питання таке погане, що воно отримало дві оцінки вниз після редагування. Я з такою реакцією ще ніде не стикався.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha підозрюю, що один з мінусів був до редагування. І bytebuster його обґрунтував у коментарі. Поведінку improbable у цьому випадку не підтримую і відверто про це написав. На зараз є один мінус. Цілком нормально, бо, наприклад, немає спроби самостійно відповісти на питання, що є одним із критеріїв. Щодо "ніде не стикався", то я стикався не раз на сайтах анґлійської й німецької мов. І нічого страшного. Мені навіть сьогодні на питання місячної давнини на інґліші поставили мінус, але то мене не демотивує аж так.

Comment: Питання ж було конкретно до читачів Гаррі Поттера. Якщо не читав, то чому ставити мінусову оцінку? Бо не знаєш відповіді? Не розумію… А особисто я не зміг відповісти на це питання, бо для того щоб знайти його переклад в українському тексті, потрібно знати де воно зустрічається в англійському тексті.  А англійський текст складно знайти.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha слухайте, ви зараз з одного мінуса зробили якісь такі дивні претензії. Кожний користувач, якщо йому щось не подобається, має право поставити той мінус. Якщо вас не влаштовує на таке запитання розподіл 5 плюсів на один мінус, думаю, я вас не можу заспокоїти й ніяк допомогти чи щось пояснити. Ви не ведете конструктивної бесіди. Ви не хочете дійти спільного знаменника тощо. Сподіваюсь, вам іноді ставатиме в нагоді наш сайт. Якщо хочете, щоби було менше мінусів - таки перечитайте критерії. Якщо хочете, щоби їх не було зовсім - спробуйте влаштувати диктатуру на стеку. Успіхів.

Comment: @P.Vowk Добре, в мене не було мети ображати когось. Просто посилання вказувало не на те, що було написано тут. Крім того питання про High Table Dinner, а чогось посилання і запитання про словосполучення High Table.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha В оригіналі Гаррі Поттері НЕМАЄ слова "High Table Dinner". High Table i High Table dinner - різні речі.

Comment: @improbable, у давніх освітніх закладах був "high table". Раніше за ним їли щодня (так само робили у Гоґвортсі). В сучасних університах британської традиції залишився лише "high table dinner". Оскільки назва цієї традиції містить назву самого стола, щоб перекласти назву традиції можна поглянути на переклад назви предмету. Хіба це не очевидно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Після відповіді пана Анатолія, я здогадався пошукати [«високий стіл»](http://korpus.org.ua/search/%22%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BB%22/0/5/450) у Корпусі української мови*. Cхоже, що в українському перекладі "High Table" переклали дослівно:

> Нарешті він міг добре розгледіти Високий стіл.
>
> Гаррі, розімлівши і майже засинаючи, ще раз глянув на Високий стіл.

Тому щомісячний університетський "High Table Dinner" буде скоріше «вечерею за Високим столом».

(Вячеслав Бродовий у своєму перекладі «Пісні льоду та вогню» теж переклав дослівно і з малої: «високий стіл» — щоправда в тому контексті це не стосується освітнього життя Британії.)

Answer (score 5):

Перше слово, яке мені спало на думку - "[Бенкет](http://sum.in.ua/s/benket)". Дивимось його значення:

> Урочистий обід, сніданок або вечеря, що влаштовується на честь
>   кого-небудь або на відзначення якоїсь події.

В Гоґвортсі це справді була урочиста вечеря (наскільки я пам'ятаю) на честь початку/завершення навчального року, проведення турнірів тощо. Але якщо ми говоримо про звичайний прийом їжі (хоч він там теж нагадував бенкет) я б використав для перекладу звичайні "обід", "снідано" та "вечеря" залежно від часу доби, коли ця подія відбувалась.

Comment: є ще хороше слово "учта".